# Build errors after Android Studio 3.2.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, onesignal

I am building a project. This was working fine till now, but after upgrading to `Android Studio 3.2.1`, I am facing the build error below.

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library [com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.5] C:\Users\gaura\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\OneSignal-3.10.5.aar\0496400264bec06e5ea525577acb13c2\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 14

Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 15,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.onesignal" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

how can i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

should you use a library compatible with your project. Or if the library you use is open source, you can make it compatible. or increase your project's minsdk. Do you specify which library you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the library you are using. It is compiled against api 15 while your project is set to a minimum of api 14. The minSdkVersion should always be equal in case the library includes api's which are not available in your projects sdk version. You should increase your projects minSdkVersion to 15 or find a compatible library with minSdkversion 14